# how to validate first three digits of phone number

Tags: regex, flutter

I have a `TextFormField` for a phone number and I  want to validate the input to match my RegEx to phone number value

the valid inputs are

```
075xxxxxxxx
077xxxxxxxx
078xxxxxxxx
079xxxxxxxx
```

I tried this `r"^ (?:[0]7)?[0-9]{11}$"` but its not working

any way to do it right?

Comment: a dup of the how to validate _ALL_ phone numbers in the world ? pretty arogant isin't it ?

Answer (score 0):

Match a zero, then a 7, then any of [5,7,8,9] then any 8 digits:

```
07[5789]\d{8}
```